# Java: Making singleton less verbose

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns, interface, singleton

To help me learn Java and programming concepts, I'm writing a bot that will solve the puzzles in the game [PuzzleFreak](http://www.freeworldgroup.com/games6/gameindex/puzzle-freak.htm) .

I've made the controller for the game a singleton, since there should be only one. However, now I have `Controller.getInstance()` peppered everywhere. How can I make this less verbose? Is a Singleton even the way to go here?

I could wrap the controller methods in default methods so that I could just call `click(x,y)` in the `Player` implementations, but that feels wrong.

Below I have the Player interface and an example implementation.

Player.java:

```
public interface Player {

default void giveUp() {
    Controller.getInstance().click(new Rectangle(704, 545, 64, 18));
    Controller.getInstance().delay(0.1);
    Controller.getInstance().click(new Rectangle(704, 545, 64, 18));
}

default void play() {
    giveUp();
}
}
```

StartupPlayer.java:

```
public class StartupPlayer implements Player {

public void play(){
    Controller.getInstance().click(60, 278);
    Controller.getInstance().delay(0.5);
    Controller.getInstance().type("KevinBot");
    Controller.getInstance().delay(0.5);
    Controller.getInstance().click(400, 463);
}
}
```

Comment: You can always `Controller controller = Controller.getInstance();` and reuse `controller`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the interface, you could get the controller through a getter:

```
public interface Player {

  default void giveUp() {
    Controller controller = getController();
    controller.click(new Rectangle(704, 545, 64, 18));
    controller.delay(0.1);
    controller.click(new Rectangle(704, 545, 64, 18));
  }

  default void play() {
    giveUp();
  }

  default Controller getController() {
    return Controller.getInstance();
  }

}
```

Then, the implementation class also uses the getter:

```
public class StartupPlayer implements Player {

  public void play(){
    Controller controller = getController();
    controller.click(60, 278);
    controller.delay(0.5);
    controller.type("KevinBot");
    controller.delay(0.5);
    controller.click(400, 463);
  }

}
```

This way, it's easier to change the decision that it's a singleton later on.

Also, if you'll be calling lots of controller methods in succession, you might consider making it a [fluent interface](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/FluentInterface.html), and renaming the getter simply to `controller` (I think it makes it more fluent as well), you'd have:

```
public interface Player {

  default void giveUp() {
    controller().
      click(new Rectangle(704, 545, 64, 18)).
      delay(0.1).
      click(new Rectangle(704, 545, 64, 18));
  }

  default void play() {
    giveUp();
  }

  default Controller controller() {
    return Controller.getInstance();
  }

}

public class StartupPlayer implements Player {

  public void play(){
    controller().
      click(60, 278).
      delay(0.5).
      type("KevinBot").
      delay(0.5).
      click(400, 463);
  }

}
```

This cuts down on the verbosity even further...

And, if the default implementation you provide in the interface for `play` is really meant to be overridden every time, you should consider keeping it abstract. The method `giveUp` would still be available for implementing classes to use.

Comment: That's pretty slick! I've never heard of a fluent interface before. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Just declare a local controller and call `getInstance()` once:

For example:

```
public class StartupPlayer implements Player {
    public void play(){
        Controller controller = Controller.getInstance()
        controller.click(60, 278);
        controller.delay(0.5);
        controller.type("KevinBot");
        controller.delay(0.5);
        controller.click(400, 463);
    }
}
```

Comment: If I were to do something like this, should I make it a field of each class that implements `Player`, and possibly add it to the constructor for each class? Could I have some kind of "default constructor" for all the classes, so I won't have so much repeated code?

Answer (score 0):

Set it to a variable in the target context(s) (class); even in a variable it's the same instance. Just a different reference to the same instance.

Answer (score 0):

You can have an public Enum called **SigletonEnum** with a single instance called **INSTANCE**. 
This is a singleton.

As this is an enum, it is not required to be instantiated.And then in the application you can call it as

```
SingletonEnum.INSTANCE.doSomething();
```

Comment: That doesn't seem any better than `Controller.getInstance().doSomething()`.

Comment: I tend to use Enums as singletons as they are easier to write, they serialize by themselves and they are thread safe.

Comment: That wasn't my point. The question is about verbosity, not about how to implement a singleton. Regardless of how you implement it, you're going to access it through a field or a method. How do you make that shorter?

Comment: Yeah I noticed your point. Although the Controller.getInstance() will need code to maintain the Singleton process and not instantiate a new controller object when the method is invoked, so technically the enum approach is less verbose.